# How to set the policy Context in oracle inside sql query “mo_global.set_policy_context('S',orgid);”

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There are some views in Oracle will not have data until you set the context policy. I need to set in the SQL query so that I run the query once.

```sql
BEGIN
   MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT ('S', 82);
END;
```

I have created a function for setting the context policy.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION APPS.sset_policy_context (p_ou NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
   MO_GLOBAL.SET_POLICY_CONTEXT ('S', p_ou);

   RETURN (1);
END sset_policy_context;
```

I want to use the function in the SQL query to populate the data in the view before selecting. Something like that:

Edit 1: When I try to execute, the context is not set even for the next run, may be due to the execution order of SQL.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM RA_CUST_TRX_LINE_GL_DIST_V
 WHERE 1 = (SELECT set_policy_context (81) FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question or explained a problem. What happens when you try to do what you showed? And why can't you just explicitly set the context before querying the view? I doubt what you are trying to do is possible - for a start, trying to set and use the context at the same time would rely on the order of evaluation, which doesn't look deterministic.

Comment: @AlexPoole 
I have edited the question, I am trying to do so, because in some reporting/analysis tool, there is no pre-execution of something like that.